# Shorthand for epoch

Tags: postgresql, datetime

Is there a shorthand for the epoch instead of having to type `'1970-1-1 00:00:00'` all the time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is surprisingly `'epoch'`

```
select 'epoch'::timestamp;
timestamp
1970-01-01 00:00:00
(1 row)

select TIMESTAMP 'epoch';
timestamp
1970-01-01 00:00:00
(1 row)
```

Special date/time inputs are described in the section 8.5.1.4 [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/datatype-datetime.html):

[image: timestamps]

Comment: Oh, the magic of reading the documentation! :)